# Remove duplicate dictionaries in a list with lower value

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to remove duplicate dictionaries in Python3 list, by a value?

I have this list with dictionaries:

```
data = [
    {'number': 42804420, 'price': 1450, 'desc': 'aaa'},
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 11500, 'desc': 'bbb'},  # <-- same 'number'
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 10000, 'desc': 'ccc'},  # <-- same 'number'
    {'number': 42380410, 'price': 1400, 'desc': 'ddd'},
    {'number': 45547080, 'price': 1050, 'desc': 'aaa'},
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 1800, 'desc': 'aaa'},   # <-- same 'number'
    {'number': 42074330, 'price': 2700, 'desc': 'bbb'}
]
```

And I am trying to figure out, how to remove duplicates sorted by price - it will check a "number", sort it by price and keep only the highest price and other ones will be removed.

So the expected result will be:

```
data = [
    {'number': 42804420, 'price': 1450, 'desc': 'aaa'},
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 11500, 'desc': 'bbb'},  # <-- keep only this one
    {'number': 42380410, 'price': 1400, 'desc': 'ddd'},
    {'number': 45547080, 'price': 1050, 'desc': 'aaa'},
    {'number': 42074330, 'price': 2700, 'desc': 'bbb'}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple O(n) solution without using any library:

```py
dataNoDups = {}

for d in data:
  if not (d['number'] in dataNoDups) or d['price'] > dataNoDups[d['number']]['price']:
    dataNoDups[d['number']] = d

print(dataNoDups.values()) # your expected result is there
```

Comment: It was the best solution without any library and it does exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

A plain python version, simply because I hate pandas with a passion.

The built-in groupby doesn't sort, so we do that first. The sort outputs the lowest price first, so we pick the last one to get the highest price.

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    {'number': 42804420, 'price': 1450, 'desc': 'aaa'},
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 11500, 'desc': 'bbb'},  # <-- same 'number'
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 10000, 'desc': 'ccc'},  # <-- same 'number'
    {'number': 42380410, 'price': 1400, 'desc': 'ddd'},
    {'number': 45547080, 'price': 1050, 'desc': 'aaa'},
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 1800, 'desc': 'aaa'},   # <-- same 'number'
    {'number': 42074330, 'price': 2700, 'desc': 'bbb'}
]

def get_sort_key(d):
    return (d['number'], d['price'])

def get_group_key(d):
    return d['number']

sorted_data = sorted(data, key=get_sort_key)

output = []
for number, items in groupby(sorted_data, get_group_key):
    output.append(list(items)[-1])
```

Comment: This looks that it works like charm, I will test it again, thank you very much!

Comment: This is a great solution and works well, thank you very much for your time, I really appreciated it. Only thing, that it will sorts results upside down, but it is not a problem in this case. I will vote this up, and I will accept a solution without a library. Thanks!

Comment: You could reverse the `sorted_data` I guess. It would also depending on the sorting of `number` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using pandas for handling tabular data like this.
Then you could do:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'number': 42804420, 'price': 1450, 'desc': 'aaa'},
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 11500, 'desc': 'bbb'},  # <-- same 'number'
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 10000, 'desc': 'ccc'},  # <-- same 'number'
    {'number': 42380410, 'price': 1400, 'desc': 'ddd'},
    {'number': 45547080, 'price': 1050, 'desc': 'aaa'},
    {'number': 46279370, 'price': 1800, 'desc': 'aaa'},   # <-- same 'number'
    {'number': 42074330, 'price': 2700, 'desc': 'bbb'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.sort_values(by=["price"], ascending=False)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["number"])
print(df)
```

should do exactly what you need

Comment: Thank you! This works well, but it will keep only the first number value - it does not take into account the price.

Comment: you can use df.sort_values before dropping duplicates. check my edit. by the way, why am i getting downvoted??

Comment: This downvote is not from my side. It keeps only the first value, for example, if the first number will be lower, for example, there will be 46279370 with value 1111 as the first dictionary

Comment: my bad, forgot to add "ascending=False", which allows us to sorts from highest price to lowest. without it its lowest to highest which is why it keeps the 1800 one in this case